# Unable to load resource Jar file

Tags: java, javafx, jnlp

I'm working on JavaFx project, and we need to run the app on java jnlp.
We singed all the jar files, and i added the IP address into Java configuration, but i faced this problem

```
 ExitException[ 3]com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://192.168.1.16:8080/walleterp/lib\WalletERPLibs.jar
at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.downloadResources(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[image]

I tried :

- Change the network setting on Java Config, and i changed it to 'Direct Connection'.
- Clear the temporary folder.
- Changed the Browser Proxy

but nothing changed for my error.
How can i solve the problem

Comment: This file is already exist in the path... Should declare it in another way ?

Comment: Why is that URL pointing to a local server? Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: I didn't find any resources about JaNeLA, the website is down, and no articles and references for that, Can you help me.

Comment: *"the website is down"* I just checked it a moment ago, it's back. JaNeLA (`janela.jar`) It is a small tool I wrote to validate JNLP files and check other things, like the availability of resources.

Comment: Is this the website URL 'http://pscode.org/janela/' ?! If not, please provide me the correct URL :)

Comment: That used to be a site of mine. I let it go and those files aren't available any longer. The tool is pretty simple though, and the error messages are either produced by a validation API & can be Googled, or otherwise self explanatory (hopefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is not something directly related to your *client-side web-start*.
Try the following :

Try to access the jar file directly from browser `http://192.168.1.16:8080/walleterp/lib/WalletERPLibs.jar`, and verify if the download is correct using your favorite compression tools  (I am using winrar) and check the file.

If not accessible (and probably is) check the following :

- **project and file names capitalization**, since java web/applications
  servers are case sensitive.
- some application servers (wildfly) restricts jar files download
  for security reasons, please **provide your web-server, however this is
  not available in tomcat**.
- **Check your web.xml** for any configured *Servlet* *Filters* that may
  interrupt your request.