# Load applet resources with size more than 40 MB

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, pack

I have an application where my applet size is only 22kb but the resources the applet files uses(configured in JNLP file) are the jar files with size more than 40 MB and it causing the application to fail. Is there any way to run the application properly with this size ?

Comment: What does _"it causing the application to fail"_ mean? Be specific with what error you get and what have you tried to solve it etc.  Also you can keep those resources outside the jar file right? Read this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081215/access-a-resource-outside-a-jar-from-the-jar

Comment: It is taking too long to load, and after it loads I can not see a jar file with size of 40 mb loaded in resurces of java where all other jars are loaded. I have the resources outside the applet file.

Comment: What does your log file print? Where does you program get struck? Post the stacktrace. Did you debug the application? Post relevant details for us to help you.

Comment: I cant see any log file generated, my applet program haven't run because the applet is not loaded. My problem is I cant load a resource jar file mentioned in JNLP file of my web application because of its size(40 mb)

Comment: HI, now i have got a nexception i.e. FailedDownloadException Unable to load the jar file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846486/unable-to-load-resource-jar-file